# Faking/Hiding real image location?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to fake/hide the real image location.

Using this;

```
RewriteRule   ^/photos/(.+).jpg$  /images/$1   [R]
```

Will only change `/photos/` to `/images/`

Is there anyway to use encoding (like base64) or something else to hide/fake real image location?

Comment: Do you really want to use `.htaccess` ?

Comment: Yes, because I think its the fastest. It shows 50 pictures in the page. What I want can be done with php file, using file_get_contents() , however, it could make a huge cpu load impact on server. Thats why I want a htaccess solution.

Comment: Well, if doing what you want using pure `.htaccess` is possible, that's beyond my knowledge. But I don't think that's the case.